# Cannot find/advertise to custom audiences created with Facebook's Tag API

Tags: facebook, target-audience

I've followed Facebook's Tag API guide to create "Custom Audiences" by using "Custom Events": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/tag-api#remarketing

The final  code reads:

```
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', 1234567890); //Of course, I'm using my own Pixel ID ;)
fbq('track', 'PageView');

fbq('trackCustom', 'Facebook Test Audience');
```

The above code seems to work just fine and the custom event is being triggered (GET requests are sent and cookies "datr" +  "fr" + "lu" set).

However, I cannot find "Facebook Test Audience" in the Ads Manager in order to advertise to it.

Does it take time to finally show up?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Just want to make sure you're doing everything mentioned here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/website-custom-audiences/getting-started, and it seems like "Facebook Test Audience" is actually an event, not an audience.

Comment: @corvuszero Yep, all configured as suggested. The event itself is trackCustom and its name would be "Facebook Test Audience". In the meantime, I was able to "solve" the issue by simply waiting for the event to show up on Facebook - I'm gonna add this answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that it simply takes some time and page views for the event to show up in Facebook Ad Manager - patience is a virtue.

And voilà, I'm able now to create a new "Custom Audience", which is based upon a "Custom Combination" of my website traffic, and select the "Event" that has been triggered by my code (named "Facebook Test Audience"):

[image]

Issue "solved"!